# Adding names or labels to the Voronoi polygons obtained from shapely.voronoi_polygons

Tags: python, geojson, shapely, voronoi-thiessen

I currently have a dataset in CSV format with around a thousand points, each has a name, latitude and longitude, I'm using those make some Voronoi polygons which in turn I'll later plot on a folium map previously converting said polygons into a GeoJSON with to_geojson() but I can't find a way in any part of the process to add the corresponding name of the central point of each region.

```python
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
points = MultiPoint(data[['long', 'lat']].values)

vor_polygons = voronoi_polygons(points)
geojson = to_geojson(vor_polygons)
```

I've tried to manually add the names with a for loop like this:

```python
geojson_dict = json.loads(geojson)

geometries = []
for i, geometry in enumerate(geojson_dict['geometries']):
  feature = {
      'type': 'Feature',
      'geometry': geometry,
      'properties': {
          'name': data.iloc[i]['name']
      }
  }
  geometries.append(feature)

feature_collection = {
    'type': 'FeatureCollection',
    'features': geometries
}
```

But the names are coming in a different order and do not correspond to any of the regions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically there will be one point (with corresponding name) inside each of the voronoi polygons so I would try to match them that way.

Some rough, untested code showing the principle:

```
geojson_dict = json.loads(geojson)

geometries = []
for geometry in geojson_dict['geometries']:
    polygon = Polygon(geometry)
    for point_row in data.itertuples():
        point = Point(point_row.long, point_row.lat)
        if polygon.intersects(point):
            feature = {
                'type': 'Feature',
                'geometry': geometry,
                'properties': {
                    'name': point_row.name
                }
            }
            geometries.append(feature)
            break

feature_collection = {
    'type': 'FeatureCollection',
    'features': geometries
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This answer was close enough, couldn't intersect over geometry directly since it's a dictionary, but converting it to a shapely geometry object allowed me to use intersects.